# How can I sort a string alphabetically if the string contains both numbers and letters?

Tags: javascript

My task is to take a string, for example:

"24z6 1x23 y369 89a 900b"

And now remove the letters from the string and return the string like so:

89 900 123 369 246 (ordered according to the alphabet letter)

Comment: Should be a matter of: 1) split string on space, 2) extract letter from each sub-string, mapping it to the number it represents, 3) sort, 4) remove letter, 5) print result.

Answer (score 2):

You could split by space, sort by letter, map only numbers and join for the result.

```js
var string = "24z6 1x23 y369 89a 900b",
    result = string.split(' ').sort(function (a, b) { 
        return a.match(/\D+/g).join('').localeCompare(b.match(/\D+/g).join(''));
    }).map(function (a) {
        return a.match(/\d/g).join('');
    }).join(' ');

console.log(result); // '89 900 123 369 246'
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is:

```js
// here we split the string of alphanumerics by a string
// of one or more ('+') white-characters, using
// String.prototype.split() with a regular expression
// to find white-space characters ('\S'), then
// use the anonymous function of the Array.prototype.sort()
// function:
var sorted = "24z6 1x23 y369 89a 900b".split(/\s+/).sort(function(a, b) {
  // a: the first element being compared,
  // b: the second element being compared

  // in each we find the first alphabetical character
  // using String.prototype.match() with a regular expression
  // to match alphabetical characters (\D); and sorting
  // based on whether the assessment of a... > b... is true
  // or false.
  return a.match(/\D/) > b.match(/\D/);

// iterating over the sorted array using Array.prototype.map():
}).map(function(el) {
  // el is the current array-element of the Array over
  // we're iterating.

  // here we return the current Array element having first
  // used String.prototype.replace() to remove all 
  // alphabetical characters (\D) globally (g) from the String:
  return el.replace(/\D/g, '');
});

console.log(sorted); // ["89", "900", "123", "369", "246"]
```

Comment: Ah; I forgot to rejoin the Array back together. Oh, well; I had wondered about the down-vote...

Comment: it's not the joining, but the order.

Comment: @Nina: I'm not seeing a discrepancy between your own order and the order from my own solution. This may be the out-dated version of Chrome I'm using at work, though. Weird. :/

Comment: i use edge, and i see `246 123 369 89 900`, but you are right, on chrome, as on ff it is `89 900 123 369 246`, so it seems to be browser dependent. i suppose, it is the sorting, you use.

Answer (score 0):

One apparent approach seems to be this:

```js
var str = "24z6 1x23 y369 89a 900b";
var strArray = str.split(' ');
console.log(strArray); // prints ["24z6", "1x23", "y369", "89a", "900b"]

// Then we sort the array alphabetically using Regex
strArray.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.match(/\D/) > b.match(/\D/)
});
console.log(strArray); // prints ["89a", "900b", "1x23", "y369", "24z6"]

// Next we remove the alphabets out of sorted array
var result = strArray.map(function (each) {
  return each.replace(/\D/g, '');
});
console.log(result); // prints ["89", "900", "123", "369", "246"]

// finally join the array with spaces to get your desired output
var output = result.join(' ');
console.log(output); // prints 89 900 123 369 246
```